# How to write a word at the end of a line with bash

Tags: bash, sed, echo

I have a conf file like:

```
mon host = 1.1.1.1
cluster = test
```

I want to write new ip end of "mon host" like:

```
mon host = 1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2
cluster = test
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do it with `sed`:

```
sed '/^mon host =/ s/$/, 2.2.2.2/' your.conf
```

Use `-i` to change the file instead of printing to STDOUT.

Comment: I dont know why but your command delete inside the file.  but this is works "sed 's/mon host = .*/&, 2.2.2.2/' my.conf -i" Thank you for your help.